# What power levels do the Baofeng UV-5R/5RA/5RE have?

Tags: rf-power, baofeng, uv-5r, power

What are the power settings of handheld radios of the Baofeng UV-5R series in **watts**?

Comment: Hi manarinian, and welcome to the Amateur Radio SE! As part of curating quality questions, we ask everone to at least lightly research their question and share what they may have found. Since the answer to this is so easily found with the simplest google search, I'm voting to close this particular question. Hope to see other posts from you soon!

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I probably should have refrained from answering given how obvious the answer was. I'll let the community decide what to do with this one.  Though I was trying to be cognizant of the fact that not every SE visitor may use English as their first language, which might affect web searches. (Thus, I skipped the deletion vote.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because one could easily Google the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [Baofeng UV-5R Features and Specifications](https://www.baofengsupport.com/baofeng-uv-5r-features-specifications/)

> 4W/1W Transmit Power

"Specification" is the key word you'd want to use in relation to questions about the capabilities and limitations of any radio equipment, including the RF power output.

I found this by putting "Baofeng UV-5R specification" into a web search.